# How to get rid of label generated with django forms

Tags: python, django

**Aim**: to just have 2 input boxes without a label on top. 
**Problem**: using django form app, a label appears on top of input boxes (see image).
[image: what the page looks like]

My models.py code is:

```py
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.


class Customer(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name + ', ' + self.last_name
```

My 0001_inital.py is

```py
# Generated by Django 2.1.7 on 2019-11-01 19:21

from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Customer',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True,
                                        primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('first_name', models.CharField(max_length=200)),
                ('last_name', models.CharField(max_length=200)),
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: Then how will people know what the first name and what the last name is?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem placeholder

Comment: @fharris it's your site and you can do as you wish, but using placeholder text as a substitute for a label makes your site much less accessible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set [**`verbose_name`**--(django doc)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#verbose-name) to *empty string*

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name + ', ' + self.last_name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [render the form manually [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually), for example without the label:

```
<form method="post" action="…">
    {{ form.non_field_errors }}
    <div>
        {{ form.first_name.errors }}
        {{ form.first_name }}
    </div>
    <div>
        {{ form.last_name.errors }}
        {{ form..first_name }}
    </div>
</form>
```

In your `ModelForm`, you can specify a placeholder, for example:

```
class CustomerForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        widgets = {
            'first_name': TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'First name'}),
            'last_name': TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Last name'})
        }
```

It might however be better to take a look at form renderers like [**`django-crisply-forms`** [readthedocs]](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) with logic that renders forms in a generic way.